# How to Over ride BindAuthenticator handleBindException for Spring LDAP Authentication setup in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

For Spring security setup in Spring Boot. The LDAP Authentication provider is configured by default to use BindAuthenticator class.

This Class contains method

```
/**
* Allows subclasses to inspect the exception thrown by an attempt to bind         with a
* particular DN. The default implementation just reports the failure to     the debug
* logger.
*/
protected void handleBindException(String userDn, String username,     Throwable cause) {
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
logger.debug("Failed to bind as " + userDn + ": " + cause);
}
}
```

This Method is to handle the authentication related Exceptions like invalid credentials.

I want to over-ride this method so i can handle this issue and return proper error message on the basis of error codes returned by LDAP. like invalid password or the account is locked.

Current LDAP implementation always returns "Bad Credentials" that does not give the right picture that why my credentials are invalid. i want to cover the cases

1. where the account is Locked
2. password is expired so i can redirect to change password
3. account locked due to number of invalid password retries

Please help

Comment: Should it... Do you really want to return that to your end user? From a security perspective yu don't want to expose that information. If an account is locked, a hacker now knows that it has a valid username. The same is you tell him the password is wrong or if a username doesn't exists.

Comment: @Denium i am building this for internal app only the Staff member can access into intranet. So this is expectation from my product Owner :)

Comment: From a security perspective that doesn't matter. Who says all users are good willing, what about disgruntled employees. I can imagine you might want this information in your logs, but you want to be as generic possible to the outside world

Comment: True. but for many reasons either logging or more visibility towards my corporate internal users. There should be a way to extend this. at the moment in spring boot configuration for security mode this seems not possible.

Comment: Also the other possibilities of use cases like expired password. where the credentials are valid. and account Locked where again the credentials are valid. i am unable to capture the cases.

Comment: Depending on what yu do that all is already logged and again you don't want to tell a hacker that an account is locked or a password expired. Which means he is on the spot. Even if it might appear that an application is only visible at the local intranet. Also Spring Security already does a lot of logging of that (if you have enabled it) and as stated in the javadoc if you want something else extend this class and configure Spring Security to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue i fixed by defining the LDAP context instead of using the Spring Boot LDAPAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.

Then created the FilterBasedLdapUserSearch and Over-written the BindAuthentication with my ConnectBindAuthenticator.

i created a separate LDAPConfiguration class for spring boot configuration and registered all these custom objects as Beans.

From the above Objects i created LDAPAuthenticationProvider by passing my Custom Objects to constructor

The Config is as below

```
 @Bean
 public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
     DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(env.getProperty("ldap.url"));
     contextSource.setBase(env.getProperty("ldap.base"));
     contextSource.setUserDn(env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn"));
     contextSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ldap.managerPassword"));
     return contextSource;
 }

 @Bean
 public ConnectBindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator() {
     ConnectBindAuthenticator connectBindAuthenticator = new ConnectBindAuthenticator(contextSource());
     connectBindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch());
     connectBindAuthenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn")});
     return connectBindAuthenticator;
 }

 @Bean
 public LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch() {
     return new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", env.getProperty("ldap.userSearchFilter"), contextSource());
 }
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain what is env in your class?

Comment: env is the Environment class bean autowired

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your spring security configuration to add your extension of BindAuthenticator:

**CustomBindAuthenticator.java**

```
public class CustomBindAuthenticator extends BindAuthenticator {

    public CustomBindAuthenticator(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        super(contextSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleBindException(String userDn, String username, Throwable cause) {
        // TODO: Include here the logic of your custom BindAuthenticator
        if (somethingHappens()) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Custom error message");
        }

        super.handleBindException(userDn, username, cause);
    }
}
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="LDAP_URL" />
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="USER_DN" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="PASSWORD" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="USER_SEARCH_BASE" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="USER_SEARCH_FILTER" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="com.your.project.CustomBindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Hope it's helpful.